# How to merge JSON objects with sub arrays with adding objects with matching values inside the array instead of replacing them with jq?

Tags: arrays, json, merge, jq

I have two JSON objects:

```
{
  "parameter1": "object1",
  "childs": [
    { 
      "id": "child1",
      "parameter-A": "value-A"
    }
  ]
}
```

and

```
{
  "parameter2": "object2",
  "childs": [
    { 
      "id": "child1",
      "parameter-B": "value-B"
    }
  ]
}
```

and I need to merge the objects, but I don't want to get the containing arrays to be replaced, but also merged, i.e. added in case the id equals. This is what I need:

```
{
  "parameter1": "object1",
  "parameter2": "object2",
  "childs": [
    { 
      "id": "child1",
      "parameter-A": "value-A",
      "parameter-B": "value-B"
    }
  ]
}
```

I currently merge the two files with `jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' file1 file2`, but parameter-A is overwritten by parameter-B with the unwanted result where parameter-A is missing:

```
{
  "parameter1": "object1",
  "parameter2": "object2",
  "childs": [
    { 
      "id": "child1",
      "parameter-B": "value-B"
    }
  ]
}
```

I could also change the JSON structure if that would simplify a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following filter will, I believe, produce the desired result in the particular case that has been presented, but the general requirements are unclear, so it may be necessary to make adjustments accordingly:

```
def add_merge($one; $two):
  def pairwise_add:
    transpose
    | map(if .[0].id == .[1].id then add else . end);
  reduce ($one|keys_unsorted[]) as $k ($one+$two;
     if ($one[$k]|type) == "array"
     then .[$k] = ([$one[$k], $two[$k]] | pairwise_add)
     else .
     end);
```

For the given pair of objects, the result is:

```
{
  "parameter1": "object1",
  "childs": [
    {
      "id": "child1",
      "parameter-A": "value-A",
      "parameter-B": "value-B"
    }
  ],
  "parameter2": "object2"
}
```